# What is the best way to receive messages from embedded broker within same message?(ActiveMQ)

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Currently there is a embedded broker running in my application, and I want to consume the queue within the same application in different thread. It works when I use `TCP Transport`, but I found I can not use `VM Transport` when the broker and the consumer in the same application. (It works if I create another process for consumer) Is there a better way to do in my situation?

Broker config with Spring

```
<amq:broker  id="myBroker" brokerName="myBroker">       
    <amq:transportConnectors>    
        <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:7777" />
        <amq:transportConnector uri="vm://myBroker" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
</amq:broker>
```

Consumer

```
public class TestConsumer {
    private static String brokerURL = "tcp://localhost:7777";
    private static transient ConnectionFactory factory;
    private transient Connection connection;
    private transient Session session;

    public TestConsumer() throws JMSException {
        factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerURL);
        connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    }

    public void close() throws JMSException {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }               
    public Session getSession() {
        return session;
    }

}
```

Listener

```
public class Listener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            //do something here
            System.out.println(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

}
```

In Main

```
TestConsumer consumer = new TestConsumer();
Destination destination = consumer.getSession().createQueue("TESTQUEUE");
MessageConsumer messageConsumer = consumer.getSession().createConsumer(destination);
messageConsumer.setMessageListener(new Listener());
```

It works when brokerURL is "tcp:localhost:7777" or is "vm://myBroker" but Broker and Consumer are in different processes. I just can not use VM Transport when the two are in the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to  use VM trnasport. If I understand you correctly your application sends and receives messages itself. In this case VM transport is the best choice: it even does not exit your JVM and transfers messages using direct API calls.

See this article for details.
http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html

Comment: I totally agree. But I just can not make it works when putting them all into the same application. Will post my code in minutes.

Comment: By the way, messages are sent from outside. Will it make difference?

Comment: Thanks for reply, finally I found I just made some mistakes by myself. VM transport is actually most suitable for my situation. And it works as what it should now.